# newbie want to create an animation to my website

Tags: flash, animation

I'm writing a private website.
I want to add an animation of a paper (which moves a bit in its conrners).
I paln the user to add some text in the text area in that animated paper.
My program will read the text and save it.
The next time the user comes I'll show him this animated paper with the text he wrote.

1) As a newbie to animation. Should I use flasf? Is there a nice freeware and simple alternative?
I saw this site but thought maybe someone can tell from his own **experience**

2) How can I include text area in an animated paper?

3) How can fill animated paper with the saved data later on ?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)
This can be done in Flash. You need to look up some things:
 1. Embedding fonts
 2. Working with Textformat
 3. Timeline animation or Tweens

2)
This depends of the complexity of your animation. You can add a DYNAMIC textfield inside your animation and give it an instance name to access it and change content.

3)
You need to retrieve the data from your saved location and then pass it into the DYNAMIC textfield myAnimation.textfield.text = loadedData.

You can save the data to a server using PHP and MySQL or you can use Flashs buildin cookie system called SharedObject (google it). Its up to you to decide.